# How to sort an array of objects by property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

How to sort this data by `score` and display it in a `<table>`?

```
[
  { "name": "xyz", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "score": 0 },
  { "name": "abc", "email": "abc@gmail.com", "score": 1 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  { "name": "xyz", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "score": 0 },
  { "name": "abc", "email": "abc@gmail.com", "score": 1 }
].sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
const table = document.createElement('table');
document.body.append(table);
const tr = document.createElement('tr');
table.append(tr);
for (const key of Object.keys(data[0])) {
  const th = document.createElement('th');
  th.textContent = key;
  tr.append(th);
}
data.forEach(datum => {
  const trB = document.createElement('tr');
  table.append(trB);
  Object.values(datum).forEach(value => {
    const td = document.createElement('td');
    td.textContent = value;
    trB.append(td);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks !! It works ! Any way to get only the unique records ?

Comment: `const uniqueRecords = [...new Set(data.map(o => JSON.stringify(o)))].map(s => JSON.parse(s));`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
  { "name": "xyz", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "score": 0 },
  { "name": "abc", "email": "abc@gmail.com", "score": 1 }
]

data.sort(function(a, b){
   return a.score - b.score;
})
```

Comment: That's for sorting, first i have to show it in a table

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do it like this. It will sort by the "score".

```js
list = [
  { "name": "xyz", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "score": 3 },
  { "name": "abc", "email": "abc@gmail.com", "score": 2 },
  { "name": "ert", "email": "ert@gmail.com", "score": 0 },
  { "name": "zsr", "email": "zsr@gmail.com", "score": 1 }
]

list.sort((a, b) => (a.score > b.score) ? 1 : -1)

console.log(list)
```

Comment: And how should i show it in the table ?

Comment: Do you mean a table on a webpage?

Comment: Any way to get the unique records from there ?